# Error with using getting OAuth token using GAE appcfg tool

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth

I am trying to hook a GAE project into our CI/automated build process.

I'm running into an issue with using appcfg - I read docs [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Passwordless_Login_with_OAuth2) saying that a permanent token could be created for doing deployments using the --oauth2 flag. I tried this and I get the following error:

> C:\dwinq-ci\dependencies\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1\bin>appcfg.cmd --oauth2 update C:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/fd63022f430f2b8c/war
>   Either the code entered is invalid or the token was revoked.

If I try the command a second time, I get a different error:

> C:\dwinq-ci\dependencies\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1\bin>appcfg.cmd --oauth2 update C:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/fd63022f430f2b8c/war
>   Bad argument: no JSON input found
>   usage: AppCfg [options]  [] []

This error is corrected by deleting a file created under my user directory, named .appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java

Deleting the file only causes the first error to occur again though.

Assistance with this is greatly appreciated. Right now, the only alternative I have is to manually go to the CI server and recreate the temporary token on a regular interval. This is not a good long-term solution.

Comment: John, are you using a Google Apps account for this? Your company may have a security policy that is causing the token to be revoked.

Comment: I would use a Google Apps account, but it does not even get to the point of asking me to login. It just fails immediately.

Comment: This seems related to issue http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8300. We are looking at it. Are you getting any other messages besides "Either the code entered is invalid or the token was revoked"? Like a Connection timeout?